# Prove that the polyhedron has at least $2^n$ vertices

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Let A be the *n* x *n* identity matrix and let **b** be the *n* x 1 vector with every entry equal to one. Prove that the polyhedron *P*(A, **b**) has at least 2$^n$ vertices.

What I have so far:

*P*(A, **b**)= set of **x** $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ so that

$\begin{bmatrix} -I_n \\A\end{bmatrix}$ **x** $\leq$ $\begin{bmatrix} **0** \\**b**\end{bmatrix}$

is satisfied. The 0 is the zero vector.

Therefore we will have the constraints *x*$_1$, *x*$_2$, ..., *x*$_n$ $\geq$ 0 and *x*$_1$ $\leq$ 1, *x*$_n$ $\leq$ 1, ..., *x*$_n$ $\leq$ 1. We will have 2*n* constraints. To make the proof a little less wordy, I've called the first set of constraints "0 constraints" and the second set of constraints "1 constraints" - this is just for my draft proof.

The number of vertices will be: 1 + *n* - 1 + *n*$^2$

The 1 comes from the origin always being a vertex as it is where the 0 constraints all intersect

The *n* - 1 comes from there being an intersection between every 1 constraint with every other 1 constraint except when the constraints are the same

The *n*$^2$ comes from there being an intersection between every 0 constraint and every 1 constraint - since we have *n* of each constraints, we get *n*$^2$.

That's where I get stuck. I think I'm heading in the correct direction but my counting or something is off.

Comment: Hint: consider the cases $n\in\{1,2,3\}$ that you can visualize.

Comment: I considered those cases and ended up with n = 1: 3 vertices, n = 2: 4 vertices; n = 3: 5 vertices. Is that what you meant?

Comment: What are your 3 vertices for $n=1$?

Comment: The $n=1$ case is the interval $0\le x_1\le 1$, which has two vertices.

Comment: By the way, this polytope is called the *unit hypercube*.

Answer (score 1):

For every variable, $x_i$, you can pick it to be $0$ or $1$ to make it a vertex, that is for each variable, you have two choices.

Since there are $n$ variables, you have $2^n$ choices.